# How to split with first occurrence of character

Tags: regex

I have this lines which :

```
POS_17=78n(18n,100n)n
WOS<8s(4s,5s)s=Pos:D4 Facebook F:5/8 Rack
```

I have a problem with this regex as below:

```
^\s*([^_]+)(_\w+)?([<>=])(.*)\s*$
```

The problem that if there are = or < or > in the same line, it's take last apparence one of these character  `< > =` .
My problem is in second line. You can check it https://regex101.com/r/PDACQl/1

Expected Result :

```
**For First line :**
POS_17=78n(18n,100n)n

Group 1.    POS
Group 2.    _17
Group 3.    =
Group 4.    78n(18n,100n)n

**For second line :**
WOS<8s(4s,5s)s=Pos:D4 Facebook F:5/8 Rack

Group 1.    WOS
Group 3.    <
Group 4.    8s(4s,5s)s=Pos:D4 Facebook F:5/8 Rack
```

Comment: Which programming language?

Comment: Add the chars to the character class `^\s*([^_<>=]+)(_\w+)?([<>=])(.*)\s*$` https://regex101.com/r/ovvoHE/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add the chars < > and = to the first negated character class to not match them.

You can omit the `\s*` at the end as it is optional and not part of the last capturing group.

```
^\s*([^_<>=]+)(_\w+)?([<>=])(.*)$
        ^^^
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fhxW29/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
^\s*([^\W_]+)(_\d+)?([<=>])(.*\S)\s*$
```

See https://regex101.com/r/PDACQl/2